# I cannot extract code to a method in NetBeans C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, refactoring

I am writing C++ code using Netbeans.
I would like to extract pieces of code into new methods (something I am use to do in C# and Resharper)

Here is what I do: I select the group of lines I want to extract then I right click and select refactor. The menu expand and several options are displayed (Rename, move, etc).
However all the Introduce options (Variable, Constant, Field, and Method) are greyed out.

Can anyone tell me why? Is there a work around or a plugin to install?

For completeness, even if I try to select a single line of code I do not get any of the refactoring options.

Comment: Me too. I've never seen that menu item enabled in 7.3 or 8.0. Rename works, I use that a lot. But extract method never.

Comment: I will post this question on the NetBeans forum and see if I get an answer

Comment: They say that it is not implemented, the option are there only because they use the same interface of JAVA that has those options.

Comment: thanks for posting the update. Disappointing to hear though.